# Динамическая подгрузка данных в таблицу

Tags: javascript

На странице есть таблица(привел пример одной записи):

```
<div class="my__table">
                            <div class="my__table-row wallet__row">

                                <div class="wallet_a">USD</div>
                                <div class="wallet_b">
                                    <span id="full_name_USD">USD</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wallet__1">Dagger</div>
                                <div class="wallet__4">0.000000000</div>
                                <div class="wallet__2"><?php echo number_format($valid_row["usd"]/100000000,8)?></span></div>
                                <div class="wallet__3"><?php echo number_format($valid_row["usd"]/100000000,8)?></span></div>
                                <!--<div class="wallet__4">0.000<span>00000</span></div>-->

                            </div>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в таблицу автоматически подгружались данные из таблицы БД. Написал скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("timer");
  $.ajax({
    url: "market_table.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      refresh: true
    }, // Передаем данные для записи
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $('.my__table').html(function() {
          var res = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < result.History.Total.length; i++) {
            res += '<div class="my__table-row wallet__row">' +
              '<div class="wallet_a">' + "abc"+ '</div>' +
               +'</div>';

          }
          return res;
        });
      } 
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.my__table').html(function() {
        var res = '';
        return res;
      });
    }
  });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Но новые данные не добавляются в таблицу, подскажите, где ошибка?

Консоль:

```
  ERROR 
{url: "market_table.php", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, …}
accepts: {*: "*/*", text: "text/plain", html: "text/html", xml: "application/xml, text/xml", json: "application/json, text/javascript", …}
async: true
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: {xml: /\bxml\b/, html: /\bhtml/, json: /\bjson\b/, script: /\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/}
converters: {* text: ƒ, text html: true, text json: ƒ, text xml: ƒ, text script: ƒ}
crossDomain: false
data: "refresh=true"
dataType: "json"
dataTypes: (2) ["text", "json"]
error: ƒ ()
flatOptions: {url: true, context: true}
global: true
hasContent: true
isLocal: false
jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: ƒ ()
processData: true
responseFields: {xml: "responseXML", text: "responseText", json: "responseJSON"}
success: ƒ (result)
type: "POST"
url: "market_table.php"
xhr: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Консоль

```
ERROR parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ut (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

market_Table.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
session_start();
include_once('db.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $sesion_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}

//Если существует refresh то просто получаем данные с базы и возвращаем их
if ($_POST['refresh'] == "true") {
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `trade_history` ORDER BY `TimeCloseOrder` DESC ");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $History['OrderID'][]      = $row['OrderID'];
        $History['ID_prod'][]      = $row['ID_prod'];
        $History['ID_poc'][]      = $row['ID_poc'];
        $History['Price'][]   = $row['Price'];
        $History['Amount'][]  = $row['Amount'];
        $History['Total'][]   = $row['Total'];
        $History['Type'][]    = $row['Type'];
        $History['Val'][]     = $row['Val'];
        $History['Prod'][]    = $row['Prod'];
        $History['TimeCloseOrder'][]      = $row['TimeCloseOrder'];
    }
    $out = array(
        'History' => $History
    );
    // Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

    // Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
    echo json_encode($out);

    //Прекращаем выполнения скрипта
    die;
}
```

Знает кто в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "новые данные не добавляются" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor по идее, при загрузке страницы должна добавиться новая запись с одним заполненным полем, но ничего не происходит. запись добавленная вручную пропадает и на этом все

Comment: добавьте `success: function(result) { console.log(result);` - что в консоли браузера?

Comment: `error: function() { console.log("ERROR", this);`

Comment: @Igor добавил лог консоли в вопрос

Comment: А слова "ERROR" в консоли нет?

Comment: @Igor ой, извините, перед {url: написано ERROR

Comment: `error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log("ERROR", status, error, xhr.responseText);`

Comment: @Igor добавил в вопрос

Comment: Отлично. То, что возвращается с сервера, не может быть прочитано как JSON. Там еще должен быть `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: @Igor Имеете ввиду в консоли? Помимо того что я скинул, ничего нет, вот как выглдяит запрос error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log("ERROR", status, error, xhr.responseText);}

Comment: Может проблема в файле market_table.php? прикрепил код

Comment: @Igor не знаете в чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо разбираться, что же приходит на клиент и не может распарситься как JSON. Сделайте так:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("timer");
  $.ajax({
    url: "market_table.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      refresh: true
    },
    dataType: "text", // !!!
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("SUCCESS","[",result,"]");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("ERROR", status, error, xhr);
      console.log("[",xhr.responseText,"]");
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Зачем у Вас `die;` в коде?

Comment: в консоли пусто, только таймер

Comment: вот что щас выводит: SUCCESS [  ]

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Ну вот Вам и причина. С сервера приходит пустой ответ, который, естественно, не является JSON-ом.

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Уберите `die;` из кода

Comment: почему он так криво выводит? посмотрите скрин пожалуйста

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Этот вопрос слишком разбух. Задайте, пожалуйста, новый - с минимум кода и разметки.